Fitch-style proof: Given $\forall x.(p(x)⇒¬q(x))$ and $\exists x.p(x)\Rightarrow∀x.q(x)$, prove $\lnot\exists x.p(x)$.
This is a Fitch Proof exercise from Stanford's Introduction to Logic on Coursera.
Given the premises
$1.  \forall x \, (p(x) \Rightarrow \neg q(x)) $
$2. \exists x \, p(x) \Rightarrow \forall x \, q(x)$
Prove the goal:
$ \neg \exists x \, p(x) $
I saw premise 2 and thought I should derive $\exists x \, p(x) \Rightarrow \neg \forall x \, q(x)$ to do a negation introduction. To do that I assumed $\exists x \, p(x)$ and tried to derive $\neg \forall x \, q(x)$ but then hit a wall.
I hope someone can point out if I'm going in the right direction and what I am missing. Thank you.


I saw premise 2 and thought I should derive ∃xp(x)⇒¬∀xq(x)
to do a negation introduction. To do that I assumed ∃xp(x)
and tried to derive ¬∀xq(x)
but then hit a wall.

As you seek to do this, then I suspect that your system's negation introduction rule may be: $$\begin{split}&A\to B\\ &A\to\neg B\\\hline&\neg A\end{split}$$
If this is so, then you may derive $\neg\forall x~q(x)$ by the same means: under the assumption of $p(c)$ derive $\forall x~q(x)\to q(c)$ and $\forall x~q(x)\to\neg q(c)$, to thus infer $\neg\forall x~q(x)$.  Then $\exists$ elimination.
$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{\forall x~(p(x)\to\neg q(x))
\\\exists x~p(x)\to\forall x~q(x)}{\fitch{\exists x~p(x)}{\fitch{\boxed c~p(c)}{\fitch{\forall x~q(x)}{~~\vdots\\\neg q(c)}\\\forall x~q(x)\to\neg q(c)\hspace{4ex}{\to}\text{intro}\\\fitch{\forall x~q(x)}{~~\vdots\\q(c)}\\\forall x~q(x)\to q(c)\hspace{6ex}{\to}\text{intro}\\\neg \forall x~q(x)\hspace{12ex}{\neg}\text{intro}}\\\neg\forall x~q(x)\hspace{15.5ex}\exists\text{elim}}\\ \exists x~p(x)\to\neg\forall x~q(x)\hspace{7.5ex}{\to}\text{intro}\\\neg\exists x~p(x)\hspace{18.5ex}{\neg}\text{intro}}$$

By $\neg$-introduction, we assume $\exists x. p(x)$ and derive a contradiction. By assumption, there is a $y$ such that $p(y)$. Hence by 1, $\neg q(y)$. But by 2 we also have $q(y)$, a contradiction.
